# Is it possible to toggle a class onclick if the button is in a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components and want to toggle a class. But, the class I want to toggle is in another component and it doesn't function at all.

filter.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const filterNav = (props) => {
  const [gridOne, gridTwo] = useState(false);
  const toggleClass = () => gridTwo(!gridOne);

  return (   
    <div>   
      <a onClick={toggleClass}>
        <span className={gridOne ? 'fa fa-icon fa-th-large' : 'fa fa-icon fa-th-list'}></span>
      </a>

      <div className={gridOne ? 'block' : 'hide'}>Test</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default filterNav;
```

The above example works perfectly (I am using the test div to show it works in the same file). The issue I am having is that the button I want to use for toggling is in `filter.js` and the class I want to toggle is in `layout.js` (`className={gridOne ? 'col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch' : 'col-md-12'}`)

layout.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function hitItems(props) {

  const [gridOne, gridTwo] = useState(false);
  const toggleClass = () => gridTwo(!gridOne);

  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div className={gridOne ? 'col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch' : 'col-md-12'}>
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          {props.topics &&
            <div className="tags-inner">
              {props.topics.map(topic => (
                <div className="card-tag">
                  <span className="home-link track-click">{topic.name}</span>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default hitItems
```

Is it possible to toggle a button onclick in one component and have it change another? I can rework the question if this is confusing

Comment: Sounds like the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is what you're after.

Comment: It's possible if you use your filter.js component inside your layout.js component, if they`re not child-parent you need to use redux or context API

Comment: if they're parent-child you just need to set your toggleClassFunction in the parent and pass the through props to the child, and then call it on child's onClick

Answer (score 0):

The thing is there is no connection between filter.js and layout.js, so you can't know the state of filter.js in layout.js. Can you please check the guide props and states between components ?

Answer (score 0):

`hitItems` doesn't need its own state if it depends on `filterNav`'s state.

The confusion might arise because `useState` don't share states in each component.
Just because you named states the same, that doesn't mean they are the same state.

You can pass `filterNav.gridOne` to `hitItems` as a prop and use it.

*And also capitalize your component names as `HitItems` or `FilterNav`.

It might work as your components are exported as defaults.

React requires components with a capitalized letter.*

```js
const FilterNav = props => {
  const [gridOne, gridTwo] = useState(false);
  const toggleClass = () => gridTwo(!gridOne);

  return (
    <div>
      <a onClick={toggleClass}>
        <span
          className={
            gridOne ? "fa fa-icon fa-th-large" : "fa fa-icon fa-th-list"
          }
        ></span>
      </a>

      {/* <div className={gridOne ? "block" : "hide"}>Test</div> */}
      {/* Pass the prop to HitItems */}
      {gridOne && <HitItems gridOne={gridOne} />}

    </div>
  );
};
```

`HitItems` would simply use the prop passed without managing its own state.

```
function hitItems({topics, gridOne}) {
  return (
    <div className={gridOne ? 'col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch' : 'col-md-12'}>
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          {topics &&
            <div className="tags-inner">
              {topics.map(topic => (
                <div className="card-tag">
                  <span className="home-link track-click">{topic.name}</span>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```